# Apache Camel File Component: Specifying 1 file in regex

Tags: java, regex, file, apache-camel

I have the following Camel route (Spring XML);

```
<route id="myroute">
    <from uri="file:///home/myuser/someDir?include=toprocess_*.txt" />

    <to uri="bean:fileProcessor?method=process" />
</route>
```

And on my machine's file system:

```
/home/user/someDir/
    toprocess_1.txt
    toprocess_2.txt
    toprocess_3.txt
    ...
    toprocess_13904.txt
```

How do I change the `include` option (or the `uri` in general) so that only the **first** file (regardless of its name) matching the regex gets added to the route, and subsequently, routed on to the `fileProcessor` bean?

**Please note** that in my example, the first file will most likely be `toprocess_1.txt`. However I could have a file system like so:

```
/home/user/someDir/
    toprocess_red.txt
    toprocess_blue.txt
    toprocess_green.txt
    ...
    toprocess_black.txt
```

So it's not as simple as just making the URI:

```
<from uri="file:///home/myuser/someDir?include=toprocess_1.txt" />
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
<from uri="file:///home/myuser/someDir?include=toprocess_*.txt&maxFiles=1" />
```

But in the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/file.html), I see no such option, or anything similar to it.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to run your route just once getting just one file?

Comment: Yep, and I don't care what specific file, so long as it matches the `include` regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could do it this way:

```
<route id="myroute">
    <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
    <pollEnrich uri="file:///home/myuser/someDir?include=toprocess_*.txt" />
    <to uri="bean:fileProcessor?method=process" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 3):

The include options is using regular expression as documented

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

So you need to use a regular expression to match the wildcards, eg *. should be flipped

```
?include=toprocess_.*txt"
```

Its just a standard java regular expressions so you can find plenty of information about these on the internet, and in the javadoc of the JDK itself.